# In Visual Studio Code - how to permanently enable continuous run?

Tags: visual-studio-code, testing

I am using the TestMate extension and I start to like the continuous run feature. After rebuilding the executable the tests get run and I get notified when there is an error.

The problem is after restarting Visual Studio Code, I have to re-enable "Continuous Run".

How to prevent Visual Studio Code from forgetting to watch for changes and run the tests after restarting VS Code?

I tried it with:

- click on "Turn on Continuous Run" (the eye button next to the test)
- click on "Start Continuous Run" (the eye button on the top of the testing activity window)

System information:

```
Version: 1.86.2
Commit: 903b1e9d8990623e3d7da1df3d33db3e42d80eda
Date: 2024-02-13T19:41:37.860Z
Electron: 27.2.3
ElectronBuildId: 26908389
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.7.5-arch1-1
```